# Is there a better way to create a schema

Tags: typescript, postgresql, typeorm

For this example I have 4 schemas. `Picture`, `Video` and `Game` can have multiple `Download`.
And while it creates mess with multiple tables it works when searching downloads from invoker side (`Picture`, `Video` and `Game`).
But problem arises when i want to determine invoker from `Download` side. i need to lookup 3 many-to-many tables and then fetch my data.

Is there something in typeorm to ease my pains?
Or is this simply incorrect way of designing many to many with multiple schemas?
Did you guys face similar problem? And if yes how did you solved it?

Thanks in advance

```js
@Entity()
export class Picture {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number

    @Column()
    name: string

    @ManyToMany(() => Download)
    @JoinTable()
    downloads: Download[]
}

@Entity()
export class Video {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number

    @Column()
    name: string

    @ManyToMany(() => Download)
    @JoinTable()
    downloads: Download[]
}

@Entity()
export class Game {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number

    @Column()
    name: string

    @ManyToMany(() => Download)
    @JoinTable()
    downloads: Download[]
}

@Entity()
export class Download {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number

    @Column()
    source: string

    @Column()
    status: string

    @Column()
    path: string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given we can't assume the join technique you're using, since the schema description doesn't provide us with the relevant fields on which a join statement can be executed (I see you got `source: string`, but the other schemas have int IDs), introducing indexes on the relevant columns might speed your SELECT statements up.

I'm considering something around the following is put to use:

```
select *
from downloads d
join game g on g.id = CAST(coalesce(d.source, '0') AS integer)
join video v on v.id = CAST(coalesce(d.source, '0') AS integer)
join picture p on p.id = CAST(coalesce(d.source, '0') AS integer)
```

Now, given we had the downloads' table structured like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE Download(
id int,
source_id int,
source varchar,
status varchar,
primary key id);

create index source_id_index on Download(source_id);
```

Life would be much easier for the server, given that both the source_id in the Downloads table and the IDs in the neighboring tables were indexed; the select statement would then work faster:

```
select * from downloads d
join video v on v.id = d.source_id
join picture p on p.id = d.source_id
join game g on g.id = d.source_id
```

Now, this might also imply that the neighboring tables' IDs are not repeated. Should they be, you might also introduce some variable like `content_source_id int` and do a `case when`. Total sandbox of ideas.

There are also little details about indexes in Postgres' docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html